# MySQL not sure about aggregation function

Tags: mysql, group-by, min

I had this function many-to-many tables.

```
table Actor
-----------
Actorid     Fullname

table entertainment
-------------------------
Entertainmentid   Name   Date


Actor_entertainment
-------------------------
Entertainmentid   Actorid
```

I need to choose all Actors names and for each actor the earliest entertainment date and name that actor has.

I build this query:

```
SELECT 
a.fullname
, c.Name
, MIN(c.Date) 
FROM Actor a 
INNER JOIN Actor_entertainment b on b.Actorid = a.Actorid 
INNER JOIN entertainment c ON c.entertainmentID = b.entertainmentID 
GROUP BY 
a.Fullname
```

Query works good but I am not sure MIN function picks the right date.  Can you please read this query and tell me am I wrong somewhere? To be precise is mistake possible?

thanks.

Comment: You will get the right date. The question is whether you will get the right `entertainment.name`. If the dbms had been Oracle you would get an error if there was more than one name in any group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the minimum value of `c.Date` will be returned. And that will be the "earliest date" as long as the `Date` column is of datatype `DATE`, `DATETIME`, `TIMESTAMP`, or the values stored in that column are in a canonical format... a lower value corresponds with an earlier date.

However, the value returned for the `c.Name` expression is *indeterminate*. That is, there is no guarantee that the value returned for that expression will be from the same row the minimum date value was returned from.

(Other databases would return an error with that SQL statement, balking at a "non-aggregate" expression appearing the SELECT list without appearing in the `GROUP BY` clause. MySQL provides a non-standard extension to GROUP BY which allows this query to execute. The behavior of MySQL can be modified, to disable this extension, by setting `SQL_MODE` to include `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`.)

There are a couple of approaches to getting the `Name` associated with that earliest date.

For a small number of rows being returned, and suitable indexes available, using correlated subqueries can be workable:

```
  SELECT a.fullname
       , ( SELECT c.Name
             FROM entertainment c
             JOIN Actor_entertainment b
               ON b.entertainmentID = c.entertainmentID 
            WHERE b.Actorid = a.Actorid
            ORDER BY c.Date ASC, c.Name ASC
            LIMIT 1
          ) AS `Name`
       , ( SELECT c.Date
             FROM entertainment c
             JOIN Actor_entertainment b
               ON b.entertainmentID = c.entertainmentID 
            WHERE b.Actorid = a.Actorid
            ORDER BY c.Date ASC, c.Name ASC
            LIMIT 1
          ) AS `Date`
    FROM Actor a
   ORDER BY a.fullname
```

Another approach is to get that earliest date, and then perform a join to find the rows corresponding to that earliest date. If there is more than one row with the same "minimum" date for a given row in Actor, this will return all of those rows:

```
  SELECT da.fullname
       , dc.Name
       , dc.Date
    FROM ( SELECT a.actorid
                , MIN(c.Date) AS min_date
             FROM Actor a
             JOIN Actor_entertainment b
               ON b.Actorid = a.Actorid
             JOIN entertainment c
               ON c.entertainmentID = b.entertainmentID
            GROUP BY a.actorid
         ) d
    JOIN Actor da
      ON da.actorid = d.actorid
    JOIN Actor_entertainment db
      ON db.Actorid = d.Actorid
    JOIN entertainment dc
      ON dc.entertainmentID = db.entertainmentID
     AND dc.Date = d.min_date
```

Answer (score 0):

Using variables you create a ranking to each artist based on date, then just select the first one of each artist.

Also see instead of using alias `A, B, C` i use `A, AE, E` to help understand the query.

```
SELECT ArtistName,
       EntertainmentName,
       Date 
FROM (
        SELECT 
            A.fullname ArtistName
          , E.Name     EntertainmentName
          , E.Date
          , (@rank := if(@prev_artist = A.fullname, 
                         @rank + 1,  -- increase rank
                         if(@prev_artist := A.fullname, --reset rank
                            0, 
                            0                       
                           )
                        )                  
           ) as ranking 
        FROM Actor A 
        INNER JOIN Actor_entertainment AE
                on A.Actorid = AE.Actorid 
        INNER JOIN entertainment E 
                ON AE.entertainmentID = E.entertainmentID 
        CROSS JOIN (select @rank := 0, @prev_artist := '') params
        ORDER BY A.Actorid, E.Date
     ) T
WHERE ranking = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for advise about naming tables.